# Generating WeChat QR Codes

Tags: wechat

I' working on a login page where I want to use WeChat as login option and I have a WeChat official account. In my understanding of the documentation it's supposed that the next link would generate a QR code to scan and after the user authorization redirects somewhere else...:

https://open.weixin.qq.com/connect/qrconnect?appid=wx8bxxx21bxxxx0fxxx&redirect_uri=https://myhostname/oauth2.php&response_type=code&scope=snsapi_login&state=101#wechat_redirect

But the link doesn't work. I don't know if I'm missing something or maybe the site https://myhostname/oauth2.php has to have a previous authorization call to WeChat... ???

Somebody has worked with this WeChat stuff?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why don't you write an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized later that you must have a WeChat Open Platform Account, where you register your web application, wait for approval, and then give it the login permission to get access to that QR Code functionality

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on how to login web page after scanning qrcode of an offical account on the web page. 
There are two ways to approach this.

#### Scan service official account

You can generate the qrcode injected with parameters. then after you scan, there will be an event triggered in your backend.
Capture the event and extract the parameter, then do the authentication in the way you want.

[image]

The basic workflow:

1. app frontend request your backend for a session.
2. app backend call wechat api to generate a qrcode, injecte with any parameter you like.
3. app frontend show the qrcode.
4. user scan the qrcode of the service account.
5. if user did not subscribe, then subscribe the official account.
6. backend receive the scan event, extract the info and authenticate the user.

#### Scan subscription official account

In subscription get less programing support, but you can still achieve it by design a random code.

[image]

The basic workflow:

1. app frontend request your backend for a session.
2. app backend generate a random code.
3. app frontend show the qrcode of the official account with a random code.
4. user scan the qrcode of the subscription official account.
5. if user did not subscribe, then subscribe the official account.
6. user input the random code in the official account message UI.
7. backend receive the code and authenticate the user.
8. attach user info in your db with openid if you want.

#### Use an open platform to do it in the smart way.

If you doing this for one official account, it is ok. Let's say if you want to reuse this for multiple official accounts.
Maybe can use the open platform way, so you can have only 1 backend to handle multiple accounts.
Wechat offer an open platform, here is the  [get start doc](https://developers.weixin.qq.com/doc/offiaccount/en/Getting_Started/Overview.html).
Register an open platform need to pay 300RMB for verification, more troublesome part is, you need to register a company to be qualified to pay.
So maybe using a third party open platform will be a better choice. Such as [Dagui Qrcode Tool](https://open.vip666.cloud/qrcode).

#### Key take aways

- Use parameter Qrcode for service official account login
- Use account qrcode with random code for subscription official account login
- Use open platform for scaling
- Authentication is flexible, the key is the event exchange flow.

More secret technology related to wechat development, can refer this [article](https://www.wxhmf.com/posts/how-to-login-web-page-via-scaning-qrcode-of-a-wechat-offical-account/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the **OAuth2.0 web authorization domain** to your **subdomain** in your redirect url, such as: **wechat.myredirectdomain.com**.

This setting is hidden on the WeChat official account dev setting dashboard, some where in between the API list, make sure you set it properly.